# CMD batch - encode file to base 64 and trim characters and new line

Tags: batch-file, cmd, base64, newline, trim

### I'm trying to make a batch file from CMD with the following commands:

1. Convert file to base 64 - using certutil command this is how the contents of the base 64 looks like (B64.txt):

[image: converted B64.txt]

2. Trim the base 64 - basically, I want to remove **-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----** and **-----END CERTIFICATE-----** this part is *done*, the only thing left is trim the **newline characters** to make a one liner of base64, because I will be passing this to a request payload.

---

This is what I did so far:

```
@ECHO OFF 
cd /filePath
certutil -encode sample.pdf B64.txt
type B64.txt | find /V "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" | find /V "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" > B64.txt
```

My question is:

1. Using the command **find /V*** how can I define the new line characters and remove them?
2. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Can this also be done without assigning the base 64 as a variable? It turns out that the limit for variables is only around 9000 characters, and the base 64 I convert normally has 70,000 characters.

Comment: For variable, check the limit length  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205027/maximum-length-of-command-line-string)

Comment: Can you read a file at the beginning of a pipe and write to the same file at the end of the pipeline?

Comment: Do not paste images of text. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a really simple solution using undocumented features of CERTUTIL. You can use the
`-ENCODEHEX` verb with an undocumented format at the end to directly get your desired output of base 64 all on one line without any headers.

```
certutil -encodehex -f sample.pdf B64.txt 0x40000001
```

See the DosTips [More Tricks with certutil](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8521) thread for more information. Especially look at [this 4th post](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8521#p57918) for a detailed explanation of all the format options.

Comment: Undocumented methods can make things happen. And I do not know how many people on the level of @dbenham regarding cmd.exe. However, undocumented methods present a risk. Since they are undocumented, there is no obligation for the provider of the utility to keep them.

Comment: @lit - I said the format option was undocumented, but that is not entirely true. `certutil -encodehex /?` lists an optional `type` option, but doesn't describe what the values can be. The Windows32 API documentation for the [CryptBinaryToStringA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptbinarytostringa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) describes most of the options. It's a small leap of faith relating CERTUTIL to CryptBinaryToStringA, but the options are probably reliable.

Comment: Beautiful answer

Comment: This answer is a gold. No need to install anything or mess with powershell scripts.

Answer (score 2):

> - Edit:

You can use a **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**/**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** file with a **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code.

Then you will compile it and run it at run time to get all the strings in one line ...

- Usage:

**1)** Edit: **`cd /d "D:\Path\to\file\"`**, adding the **drive:\and\path\to\your\directory**

**2)** Save this code below as File **`OneLine.cmd`**

```bat
/* 2>nul & @cls & @echo off & title <nul & title %~nx0 & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd /d "D:\Path\to\file\" && set "_b64_file=%__CD__%\B64.txt"
"%__APPDIR__%certutil.exe" -encode -f ".\sample.pdf" "!_b64_file!" >nul 
for /f "tokens=*" %%c in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET" csc.exe
')do >2nul >nul "%%~c" /t:exe /out:"%tmp%\OneLine.exe" "%~f0" /platform:anycpu /unsafe+ /w:0 /o /nologo && goto :next

:next 
"%tmp%\OneLine.exe" & 2>nul >nul del /q /f "%tmp%\OneLine.exe" & endlocal && goto :EOF || rem :: */

using System; using System.IO;using System.Text;namespace OneLineB64 {class Program {static void Main(string[] args){
String Path = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("_b64_file");String alllines = (File.ReadAllText(Path).Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""));
alllines = alllines.Remove(0,27); alllines = alllines.Remove((alllines.Length)-25);File.WriteAllText(Path, alllines);}}}
```

- Same code in conventional formatting/layout

```bat
/* 2>nul & @cls

@echo off 

title <nul
title %~nx0

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd /d "D:\Path\to\file\"
set "_b64_file=%__CD__%\B64.txt"

"%__APPDIR__%certutil.exe" -encode -f ".\sample.pdf" "!_b64_file!" >nul 

for /f "tokens=*" %%c in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET" csc.exe')do (
   >2nul >nul "%%~c" /t:exe /out:"%tmp%\OneLine.exe" "%~f0" /platform:anycpu /unsafe+ /w:0 /o /nologo && goto :next
   )

:next 
"%tmp%\OneLine.exe"
2>nul >nul del /q /f "%tmp%\OneLine.exe" 

endlocal
goto :EOF

*/

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace OneLineB64
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         String Path = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("_b64_file");
         String alllines = (File.ReadAllText(Path).Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""));
         alllines = alllines.Remove(0,27); 
         alllines = alllines.Remove((alllines.Length)-25);
         File.WriteAllText(Path, alllines);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**[File Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8)**

**[SubString/Remove Characters in String](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/remove-last-character-from-string-in-c-sharp1)**

**[Get System Environment Variable string](https://www.csharpcodi.com/csharp-examples/System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(string)/)**

**[Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.8)**

---

> - /end Edit:

---

> Understanding the maximum character limit in the variable length, it is not possible to do it beyond **[8191 digits/characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205027/maximum-length-of-command-line-string)**

---

For remove lines you can use only certificate, because this word is present in 1st and last line.

**`certutil` + `-f`** for overwrite file out if exist

**`type B64.txt^|"%__APPDIR__%find.exe" /v "CERTIFICATE"`** will ignore the 1st and last line

**`set "_b64=!_b64!%%~b"`** will save line by line in the same variable/1 line

**`>B64.txt echo/!_b64!`** will replace/overwrite the contents of the file with the value saved in the variable (b64 strings on one line)

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd /d "d:\filePath" && set "_b64="<nul

"%__APPDIR__%certutil.exe" -encode -f sample.pdf B64.txt >nul && for /f %%b in (
'type B64.txt^|"%__APPDIR__%find.exe" /v "CERTIFICATE"')do set "_b64=!_b64!%%~b"

>B64.txt set/p "'=!_b64: =!"<nul & endlocal && exit /b
```

Same code in conventional layout:

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd /d "d:\filePath"
set "_b64="<nul

"%__APPDIR__%certutil.exe" -encode -f sample.pdf B64.txt >nul

for /f %%b in ('type B64.txt^|"%__APPDIR__%find.exe" /v "CERTIFICATE"')do set "_b64=!_b64!%%~b"

>B64.txt set/p "'=!_b64: =!"<nul 

endlocal
goto :EOF
```

---

Comment: Right, but how is it that there's a space and a new line in the end of the file? Can you check your generated B64.txt? Maybe a problem in my CMD?

Comment: Hello, sorry I didn't test it properly, but it seems that there was a problem with the file, whenever I try to decode the file back to PDF, it returns an unreadable PDF. I investigated further and tried to manually encode the PDF to base64, and I got a total length of 69,284 characters, while your code only produced 8,164 characters, why is this? Maybe it's trimming not only the new lines, but also some characters in the file.

Comment: @so_mc have you read my comment in your question? About variable limits? You can’t use cmd/bat for strings with this length in a variable, also, how to you add content to line without using any variable?. So, try using breaking line with escaping in the language you are apply this, or, put another question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it earlier, so what I want isn't possible? Can't this be done without using variables?

Comment: Yeah okay, and another thing, the part on how it trims the variable is also weird, the reason why I assumed that the converted base 64 was right was because the starting and ending characters are the same, so that means the 60,000+ characters were from the middle section, right?

Comment: Oh okay, it's just kinda hard to digest everything when I don't know much about CMD CLI :( but nonetheless, if you think this is workable, I'll also try to look for alternate solution while you work on yours. Thanks!

Comment: can you please elaborate more on how I can use this? Will I save this c# code in a bat file and then what? What parts will I replace with my path? Can you provide at least step by step? I don't get it sorry I'm quite new with this approach. Thanks!

Comment: @so_mc this is a bat file and C#, bat save as file.bat or file.cmd  and run...

Answer (score 1):

This may do what you want. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will be available.

```
SET "FILENAME=C:\src\t\sample.pdf"
SET "OUTFILENAME=C:\src\t\B64.txt"

powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "[Convert]::ToBase64String([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('%FILENAME%')) |" ^
        "Out-File -FilePath '%OUTFILENAME%' -Encoding ascii -NoNewline"
```

Comment: Hi @lit, the output is giving me a new line at the end, how can I trim that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you send link to B64.txt or content of filePath or paste text here? My OCR can't get 100% conversion, even Google Lens can't.

My understanding is you need a base 64 code in one line without headers, right?

`Certutil` can handle 70k chars. `set /p` to avoid new lines.
One line output for base64 without cert headers example:

```
certutil -f -encodehex "Fujitsu Air Con Manual.pdf" test.b64 1
for /f %i in (test.b64) do set /p=%i<nul
```

[image: One line base 64 dump]
Output may be redirected to file or via pipe for "passing this to a request payload"

Tested on Win 10: @ 2.5 Million characters.

```
dir test.b64
 Volume in drive C is Local Disk
 Volume Serial Number is 74F6-ACFC

 Directory of C:\Users\Al\Desktop

05/05/2022  12:12         **2,677,662** test.b64
               1 File(s)      2,677,662 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  54,901,383,168 bytes free

for /f %i in (test.b64) do set /p=%i<nul>> one.line
dir one.line
 Volume in drive C is Local Disk
 Volume Serial Number is 74F6-ACFC

 Directory of C:\Users\Al\Desktop

05/05/2022  13:00         **2,596,560** one.line
               1 File(s)      2,596,560 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  54,812,700,672 bytes free
```