# How to encode/decode a binary file by Windows built-in command?

Tags: python, windows, decode, encode

In python, there are base64/base85/base65536...etc. to encode a file to pure "text" format.
And it could be transferred to a "normal" file by decoding.

```
import base64
f = open(filename,'rb')
r = base64.b64encode(f.read())
print(str(r))
```

Then, by using str(r), it could be transfer file to pure text.
Could it be possible by using Windows command to do that?

Answer (score 4):

[Decoding base64 in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945780/decoding-base64-in-batch/16946681#16946681) 
I found the "certutil" command in this link.

Encode a file
`certutil -encode inputFileName encodedOutputFileName`

Decode a file
`certutil -decode encodedInputFileName decodedOutputFileName`