# base64 not recognized Windows 10

Tags: base64, fuchsia

I would like to download Fuchsia's source code.

I entered curl `-s "https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/HEAD/scripts/bootstrap?format=TEXT" | base64 --decode | bash` that I found on [fuchsia.dev](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/get-started/get_fuchsia_source#download-fuchsia-source).

I got `''base64'' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I downloaded base64 tools without success.

What should I do to make this command work?

Comment: your problem is that `base64` does not exist as command or tool in Windows, right? You can use Certutil instead as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945780/decoding-base64-in-batch

Comment: Isn't there any way to use it? What's the point of the base64 tools then? Which command should I use? Certutils doesn't seem to work like base64.

Comment: you can cut off the `| base64 --decode | bash` part and instead redirect the output to a file, e.g. `> fuchsia.b64` and then in a separate command call certutil with this fuchsia.b64 as input.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to build fuchsia from Windows directly. Most people use the [Windows Subsystem For Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) to get a Linux-like environment, and that should work.

On top of the download script, fuchsia ships with [a bunch of prebuilts](https://chrome-infra-packages.appspot.com/p/fuchsia), which are only built for linux and mac.

Answer (score 0):

Command base64 works on Ubuntu, so I could recommend you to download Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store and write the command there.

Comment: You should post this as a comment, not as an answer.