# How to create SFTP connection in Azure Data Factory using Public SSH key

Tags: azure, sftp, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create SFTP lined service (Using keys) in azure data factory.

Soruce (SFTP) team has shared public key.
But in ADF, it is asking for private key content and pass phrase.

Please help me if this is somthing source team has to share the pass phrase and private key content or do I need to generate these keys using public key shared by source.

Regards,
Srinivas.

Answer (score 2):

1. Convert your public key file into base64 string (On MAC: run in terminal `base64 -i youkey.pub`) then you can use that value for `privateKeyContent`
2. In adf connector `authenticationType` change to SshPublicKey.

passPhrase - is required only if you key is protected with password.

Also i would suggest you to store those sensitive data in keyvault

Comment: could you please let me know how to convert this using windows.

Comment: @SrinivasReddy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945780/decoding-base64-in-batch

Comment: I have tried using windows command as below   
certutil -encode pub_key.txt encodedOutputFileName.

File generated as below
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
QUFBQUIzTnphQzF5*********************************************
*************************************************************
***********************************dLS3EzaWI3eHRzUXBwRHNPa254
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

but as per the ADF document, it should start as being RSA key -------end RSA key.

Can you please help if I need to add anything to command